# It grows in summer beams

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, poetry

The answer is not hard. Just a missing word in the space at the end.

> In the end, it's what kills you.
> But before, it's what fills you.
>
> Picks you up, and lets you down.
> Fills your cup, and makes you drown.
> It will teach, and make you sound,
> Plant your feet on solid ground.
>
> Ever to and fro it goes,
> Leaping deer, and little does.
> Where you plant and farm hand hoes,
> Starts to move around your toes.
>
> It will pull, and it will tear,
> It will hurt, and it will wear,
> It's not easy, it's not fair.
> But you'll make it if you dare.
>
> And it grows in summer beams.
> And it flows in winter streams.
> Oh, it glows in honey gleams,
> And it shows, in time redeems.
>
> It is beauty, and it's strife.
> But it's love, and yes, it's ____.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the answer is

> LIFE.

*In the end, it's what kills you.*
*But before, it's what fills you.*

> Life fills you all through your ... um ... life, but when it ends, that kills you.

*Picks you up, and lets you down.*
*Fills your cup, and makes you drown.*
*It will teach, and make you sound,*
*Plant your feet on solid ground*

> Life can teach you many things, let you down in many ways, fill your existence, and show you where to go.

*Ever to and fro it goes,*
*Leaping deer, and little does.*
*Where you plant and farm hand hoes,*
*Starts to move around your toes.*

> Deer and does have life. When you plant seeds, life begins at your feet.

*It will pull, and it will tear,*
*It will hurt, and it will wear,*
*It's not easy, it's not fair.*
*But you'll make it if you dare.*

> Life isn't easy or fair, and sometimes it hurts like hell, but you survive it anyway.

*And it grows in summer beams.*
*And it flows in winter streams.*
*Oh, it glows in honey gleams,*
*And it shows, in time redeems.*

> Life is always there, at any time of year, showing itself here and there in nature.
>
>  **OP intention:** "honey" (one's spouse), "gleam" in reference to a "gleam in your eye" (the anticipation of a child), "it shows" ("showing" when pregnant), "in time redeems" (birth). This is actually what inspired the poem.

*It is beauty, and it's strife.*
*But it's love, and yes, it's ____.*

> Life can be full of beauty or full of strife ... and yes, it rhymes with strife.

Comment: You got it! There was some very specific meaning in the 5th stanza that I'm not sure was gotten, but you got the gist and put it elegantly. You cracked me up with your explanation of the 1st stanza. I meant it as a contrast between the ware life has on us, but also the fulfillment life brings. Very nice! =)

Comment: @Hawkeye Yeah, I was a little unsure about how the 5th stanza was meant to fit, but the rest seemed clear enough that it had to be the right answer.

Comment: I just realized I never explained the 5th stanza. `And it grows in summer beams.
And it flows in winter streams` rot13(Cebonoyl boivbhfyl inevbhf navzny naq cynag yvsr). But the more obscure `Oh, it glows in honey gleams,
And it shows, in time redeems.` rot13("Ubarl" (barf fcbhfr), "tyrnz" va ersrerapr gb n "tyrnz va lbhe rlr" (gur nagvpvcngvba bs n puvyq), "vg fubjf" ("fubjvat" jura certanag), "va gvzr erqrrzf" (ovegu). Guvf vf npghnyyl jung vafcverq gur cbrz. V jebgr guvf jura zl jvsr jnf certanag jvgu bhe svefg puvyq.)

Comment: @Hawkeye That's brilliant, I've added it to my answer. And congratulations :-)

Answer (score 2):

If the answer is "love," as stated in the poem, then the missing word could be:

> RIFE, as it exists "in a widespread and unchecked manner."

Comment: Oh, that's an interesting one. That does capture the negative elements in the riddle. But Rand al'Thor did get it with his answer, which I think best answer the contrasts in the riddle. Props for thinking outside the box!